# How to Consume SOAP WCF Service and REST API Together

Tags: rest, wcf, soap, asp.net-web-api2, wcf-binding

I'm writing a very basic application and it will fetch some data from database, and will pass on this data to different web services across the country.
My issue is that, the services on to which I have to pass data are WCF Services and some of them are WEB API's.
I want to consume wcf service without adding service reference, so I wont be creating a separate proxy classes for all the services, because in future we will be adding further more clients and I'll be consuming their service as well, so manually adding service reference for everyone is not the solution at the moment.

I'll be using following code to consume different wcf services:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:4684/Service1.svc");
ChannelFactory factory = new ChannelFactory<ServiceContract>(binding, address);
ServiceContract channel = factory.CreateChannel();
string resturnmessage = channel.YourMethod("test");
```

But I cannot use this method to consume REST API's, so i have to separately write a dedicated function for this, and needs to mark clients whether they have REST API or WCF Service.

Please help in this regard. thanks

Comment: Is the problem solved? If my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer. If the problem is not solved, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the `SOAP` code in a `SOAPDriver` class and the `REST` code in a `RESTDriver` class.

Then create a `WebService` class that uses SOAPDriver or RESTDriver depending on the service it's been told to communicate with.

pseudo code:

```
// Get database data
String data = getDatabaseData();

WebService webService = new WebService();
webService.send(WebService.REST, data); // REST and SOAP are variables in the WebService class

class WebService {
  public static final int REST = 1;
  public static final int SOAP = 2;

  public void send(int serviceType, String data) {
    switch (serviceType) {
      case REST:
        restDriver.send(data);
        break;
        ...
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my demo:

```
<endpoint address="REST"
    binding="webHttpBinding"
    contract="Demo_rest_ConsoleApp.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="ESEndPointBehavior"/>
<endpoint address="SOAP" 
    binding="basicHttpBinding" 
    contract="Demo_rest_ConsoleApp.IService1"></endpoint>
```

This is my WCF service. It publishes two endpoints, one is SOAP service and the other is REST service.

```
 BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8763/TEST/SOAP");
            ChannelFactory<IService1> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(binding, address);
            IService1 channel = factory.CreateChannel();
            Console.WriteLine(channel.Test());
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Call SOAP service:

[image]

```
WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
            EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8763/TEST/REST");
            ChannelFactory<IService1> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(binding, address);
            factory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
            IService1 channel = factory.CreateChannel();
            Console.WriteLine(channel.Test());
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Call REST service:

[image]

**Don't forget to add WebHttpBehavior when calling REST service:**

```
factory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.